# How to post on directly users wall in Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, api, publishing

I use this to post on users wall, but it shows a blank page, and the post doesn't appear on my wall :

```
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/user_id/feed";
$ch = curl_init();
$attachment =  array(   'access_token'  => access_token_here,                        
                    'name'          => "Rave Kenya",
                    'link'          => "www.youtube.com",
                    'description'   => 'Testing a new facebook app',
                    'message' => 'Tested',

                );

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $attachment);
$result =curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: What does `curl_error()` say?

Comment: @Pekka NOTHING I JUST GET BLANK PAGE AND NO COMMENT APPEAR ON WALL

Comment: @Pekka i use this as faceboook access token 

$facebook_access_token='186131434747415|3AxtTnZ9KcAbpZ_qXcLneddJmls'
and direct my user id 
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/100001867519270/feed";
but it stills shows blank page

Comment: Maybe acc_tok is wrong or expired?

Comment: @CappY i use my own user account and applliaction is also i dont understand whats the problem

Comment: This calls for proper debugging. Is error reporting on, and are you 100% sure there is no error message in `curl_error()`?

Comment: @Pekka how did i find this <code> curl_error()<\code> ??

Comment: @Danish `if (!$result) echo curl_error($ch);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why reinvent the wheel and not use [facebook php library](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/)?

And a step-by-step instructions are available at "[5 Steps to publish on a facebook wall using php](http://blog.theunical.com/facebook-integration/5-steps-to-publish-on-a-facebook-wall-using-php/)"

Comment: @DANISH: [here](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-post-a-message-on-the-user-wall-using-facebook-graph-api/33/) is another example of using the PHP-SDK to post to the user's wall